# Use Gitflow on two different developers' computer

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I use gitflow on my PC to develop my code. The repository is hosted on a self hosted instance of gitlab. The client I'm using is Sourcetree.

My process to create a new project is to create the main branch of the project on gitlab using its web interface. Then I clone the main branch on my PC and I use the Sourcetree button to initialize gitflow: at the end I have two local branches named `main` and `develop` and if I use the tool in Sourcetree to start a new feature it creates the `$FEATURE_NAME` branch where I can work until I finish the feature and I can use again the Sourcetree tool to end the feature and merge the branch on develop.

At this point I start working on the develop branch and I push the branch itself on gitlab to enable sharing it.

Now I'd like to work with gitflow and to take advantage of the sourcetree integration on another PC, but I don't really understand how should I proceed: I can clone the project from gitlab, but I have to choose which branch I want.

My first tought was to clone the main branch and the develop branch, but then I would miss the Sourcetree gitflow integration: I tried and I don't have the gitflow intialized so I cannot start a new feature from Sourcetree.

What is the correct procedure I should follow?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't do it on the second PC in the same way as on your first PC?

Comment: I'll edit my question to answer. Basically because the barnch develop is created during the gitflow initialization on the frist PC and then pushed on gitlab to share it on the second. If I initialize gitflow on the second PC it will create the branch there, but it will not be linked to the one on gitlab, am I right?

Comment: @effemmeffe if you point it to your repository on GitLab first, then it won't recreate the branch. Git will recognize that the `develop` branch is available on origin and will check out a new local copy of that branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [@blacktide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2446208/blacktide) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365680/use-gitflow-on-two-different-developers-computer/70365826#comment124385728_70365680), the solution is to point the repository on GitLab first, then executing git flow initialization won't recreate the branch. Git will recognize that the develop branch is available on origin and will check out a new local copy of that branch.

Answer (score 0):

Git is decentralized. Each developer has their own complete copy of the repository but in order to share code with others you need to sync your changes with a central "origin". GitLab is your "origin".

Gitflow is about creating a feature branch off of develop and merging it back. But in a distributed model we enhance gitflow by creating a pull-request to merge our feature branches back into develop.

The recommended flow:

1. clone the repository
2. switch to the develop branch
3. create a feature branch off of develop
4. push your feature branch to origin
5. use gitlab to create pull-request for your code
6. after the pr is completed, switch your local branch to develop
7. pull the latest from origin
8. delete the local feature branch

repeat 3-8 endlessly.

If you want others to work on your feature, start by cloning the repository. You only need to do this once.

1. get the latest changes from gitlab: `git fetch`
2. switch your branch to the feature branch: `git checkout feature/x`
3. use git add / commit / push to update origin with your changes
4. use git pull to fetch their changes to your machine.